# Confusion regarding service to use to implement SSO in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2c

My scenario is like this: We have multiple SaaS applications that are used by schools. These applications have different domains and handle their own user management. What we want to implement right now for users is SSO.

A bit more background, the SaaS apps are used by schools but not only the employees of the school but parents as well. The school manages all accounts for each app, so parents are given their user accounts by the school so that they can log in to the system and access some sections of the system.

--

I am confused as to what Azure service to use.

Initially I thought Entra ID as I thought they can all be considered internal users but the schools don't have MS accounts; how would the school then create the user accounts in Entra ID. The school needs to be the ones creating the users.

Then maybe they can all be considered clients so Azure AD B2C but I read that B2C, it is expected that users create their own accounts so I am not sure about this.

I am currently leaning now towards Entra External ID as it seems to describe what my scenario needs but I am not really sure.

Or is there anything else I should look into?

Answer (score 1):

In both B2C and External ID, the school needs to register as admins and then they can create users via the portal.

You then turn off sign-up so no users can register.

You can also add users via Graph API.